# Automate a scp from a windows server to a linux server

Tags: linux, windows, winscp

I need to automate a scp (every 2 hours) from a Windows server to a Linux server.

**1st step :** generate a key and copy it to linux server.
I have downloaded winscp, generated a public key and copied it to /.ssh/authorized_keys on the Linux server.
I am not even sure that at this point I have done things right.
How could I check that Linux server trusts Windows server thanks to this key? Then I can go to 2nd and 3rd steps

**2nd step :** create a scp script and test it.

**3rd step :** create a scheduled task to launch this scp command.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

What you've done so far is not bad and the rest is feasible. If you just start scp now and in the Login window under Session->Advanced->SSH->Authentication you specify your private key you generated, you should be able to login to the target machine just by giving the remote id without the password.
Once you've reached that point you can go to the further steps. If this one fails, then something is not at the right place or in the right form yet.